# Fragment_activity to new xml file in android Studio

Tags: android

Hi everyone i have developed an application using fragments, in those **fragment pages** i have developed on **login page**. After entering username and password and clicking on the loginbutton in the login page it need to redirected to another XMl File so that the user is now logged in. **I'm getting error in IF condition to start activity Intent** can anyone please help me to solve my errors.

```
package android.iiref;   

import android.app.Activity;

import android.app.Application;

import android.content.Context;

import android.content.Intent;

import android.net.Uri;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.support.annotation.Nullable;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;

import android.view.View;

import android.view.ViewGroup;

import android.widget.Button;

import android.widget.EditText;

import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */    
public class Adminlogin extends Fragment {

    Button l,iiref;
    EditText u,p;

    public Adminlogin() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_adminlogin, container, false);
        Button l = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.login_btn);
        Button iiref = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.iiref_img_btn);
        final EditText u = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.username_txt);
        final EditText p = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.password_txt);
        l.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String username=u.getText().toString();
                String password=p.getText().toString();
                if (username.equals("demo")&&password.equals("demo")){
                    Intent i = new Intent(Adminlogin.this, login.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    u.setText("");
                    p.setText("");
                }else if(username.equals("demo1")&&password.equals("demo1")){
                    Intent i = new Intent(Adminlogin.this, login.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    u.setText("");
                    p.setText("");
                }else if(username.equals("demo2")&&password.equals("demo2")){
                    Intent i = new Intent(Adminlogin.this, login.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    u.setText("");
                    p.setText("");
                }

                else{
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Invalid username or password",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    u.setText("");
                    p.setText("");
                }
            }
        });

        iiref.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent myWebLink = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                myWebLink.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.iiref.in/"));
                startActivity(myWebLink);

            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Comment: post the logcat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public class Adminlogin extends Fragment {

Button l,iiref;
EditText u,p;

public Adminlogin() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_adminlogin, container, false);
    Button l = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.login_btn);
    Button iiref = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.iiref_img_btn);
    final EditText u = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.username_txt);
    final EditText p = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.password_txt);
    l.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String username=u.getText().toString();
            String password=p.getText().toString();
            if (username.equals("demo")&&password.equals("demo")){
                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), login.class);
                startActivity(i);
                u.setText("");
                p.setText("");
            }else if(username.equals("demo1")&&password.equals("demo1")){
                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), login.class);
                startActivity(i);
                u.setText("");
                p.setText("");
            }else if(username.equals("demo2")&&password.equals("demo2")){
                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), login.class);
                startActivity(i);
                u.setText("");
                p.setText("");
            }

            else{
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Invalid username or password",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                u.setText("");
                p.setText("");
            }
        }
    });

    iiref.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent myWebLink = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            myWebLink.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.iiref.in/"));
            startActivity(myWebLink);

        }
    });
    return rootView;
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your answer Rushi, i have tried it when running my app it is closing unfortunately.

Comment: are you making any service calls?check if you are making any service call.and check if you have give the correct URL if you are doing a service call. Also check JSON parsing if you did it.

Comment: can you Post your Login.java here?

Comment: it's to long Rushi can i send it you in fb

Comment: okay.did you see whether you have done service call anywhere?

Comment: No i didn't see it. i have sent the login.java code in fb for you.

Comment: check it.if it is present send me only that part of the code

Comment: Sorry to say Rushi there is no such service call in my code. If you don't mind i will give my Team viewer id & password so that you can see my enter code. By rectifying this one error my entry app will be completed.

Comment: Gimme your mail ID.

Comment: Cool man.now you can delete the comment with your email id since this is a public site